# passing a variable to xaml page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, windows-phone

I am writing a simple windows 8.1 app.  My xaml file name is AdditionPage.xaml.  I have some code generated on the background in the AdditionPage.xaml.cs that generates two random number using the

following code:

```
namespace MathGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class AdditionPage : Page
    {
        public AdditionPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Return_Addition();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        public int AddLeftNumber_1 { get; set; }
        public int AddRightNumber_1 { get; set; }
        public int sum { get; set; }
        //public double Height { get; set; }

        // generate random numbers using the randomizer
        Random Randomizer = new Random();
```

I do not know how to display the generated numbers AddLeftNumber_1 and AddRightNumber_1 on the xaml pages.  I understand I need to use binding.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a WPF binding like that:

```
<Label Name="Name" Content="{Binding Path=YourObject.AddLeftNumber_1}" ... />
```

This is the approach you should follow.

Comment: this helps.  I must be doing something wrong still.  I updated my code above.

Comment: this helps thanks.  I am not able to get it to work still. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

A few things not right

One you are not passing a variable to the page

Two the code is not running in the background

Three not setting DataContext

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Four bind in XAML like Sophman answered  +1

```
<Label Name="Name" Content="{Binding Path=YourObject.AddLeftNumber_1}" ... />
```

You need to get a grounding on binding
[Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thank you!!  I will follow your suggestions and let you know if I have any questions.  Thanks Sophman

Comment: I can not believe how trivial this is.  I am still stack.  I made some changes to the code but I am not getting any results.  I also read the overview and used the sample code.  If you can point me to any examples I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Come on there are many many samples of binding.  I already pointed you to one.